How to extract specific data points from a CSV file?
The program is about converting a CSV file into a database. The code below is related to reading the CSV file, specifically targeting a certain range. For instance, if we want to specify reading data from column[0] "2" and rows 1 to 5, is there any way to solve this issue?
c#
private void ReadCSVAndInsertToDatabase(string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=10.24.1.239;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=true;TrustServerCertificate=true;";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] data = line.Split(',');

                    if (data.Length >= 12)
                    {
                        string query = "INSERT INTO MeasurementData (Time, Pressure, [Current], Rate, Thickness, Flow, IBV, IBC, SupV, BiasC, IBO2, IBAr) " +
                                       "VALUES (@Time, @Pressure, @Current, @Rate, @Thickness, @Flow, @IBV, @IBC, @SupV, @BiasC, @IBO2, @IBAr)";

                        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                        {
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", data[0]);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pressure", data[1]);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Current", data[2]);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rate", data[3]);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Thickness", data[4]);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Flow", data[5]);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IBV", data[6]);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IBC", data[7]);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupV", data[8]);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BiasC", data[9]);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IBO2", data[10]);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IBAr", data[11]);

                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{line}");
                    }
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}

data in csv file




Layer




10






Time[sec]
Pressure[Pa]
Current[mA]




1
0.002
44


2
0.0024
44


3
0.0031
44


4
0.0043
44


6
0.0061
44


7
0.0075
44


8
0.008
44




Can't you simply add an extract off the CSV here? I and presumably others will not download files from somewhere when its easy to add an extract (small enough to fit here and will show the problem) here.

@Ralf ok, i will

@Ralf Is it okay if I use a picture instead?

No. A.) That can't be simply copied and experimented with b.) We want to see the CSV not how its interpreted by another tool showing the content of the CSV with its own tool specific problems/lies.

Did not test the solution with an actual file, but it might give you an idea how to solve the problem. Please see code below
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) // read rows as usual
{
   if (line == "Layer") // first row should be "Layer"
   {
      line = reader.ReadLine(); // read next row

      if (line == "10")   // next row should be specific value
      {
          while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) // read rows after "Layer" and "10"
          {
              if (line == "Layer") // if line is equal to "Layer", it means you've hit the next time point
              { 
                  return; 
              }

              // Extract/Insert rows as in your question
          }
      }
   }
}

UPD:
I tested with your file and did few adjustments to the string comparison:
using var fs = File.OpenRead("C:\\Users\\yegor\\Downloads\\test_data.CSV");
var reader = new StreamReader(fs);
string? line;

while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) 
{
    if (line.StartsWith("Layer")) 
    {
        line = reader.ReadLine();

        if (line.StartsWith("10,"))  // comma is needed so we don't hit row 100, 101, 102 and so on.
        {
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) 
            {
                if (line.StartsWith("Layer")) 
                {
                    return;
                }

                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
}

Output:

Basically, you need to replace Console.WriteLine with your row insertion. The issue with previous version of my code was that even though Layer was a single value in a row, the line also had commas separating empty column values.

Please let us know how this solves the OP's problem - by editing your answer.

@Enigmativity there are comments in the code that explain every step - OP wants to get  CSV section that follows after 2 specific CSV rows.

Sorry, the line comments don't really explain how you've solved the OP's problem. What's the elevator pitch, if you like?

@YehorAndrosov I'm sorry for the delay in response. I understand the logic you've explained, but when I insert the condition to insert into the database, nothing gets updated. Could you please clarify if I misunderstood any part?

@PineapplePizza9538 Have you tried debugging and stepping through your code?

@Dijkgraaf Yes, I tried it. Do you want me to update the current code to see if I did something wrong?

@YehorAndrosov I've identified the issue. It seems to be a file access problem between the copied file and the original file. All original files are currently inaccessible to the code. The next issue is trimming the header before inserting it into the DB and specifying the desired rows. I'll update you again once I've fixed all of these issues.
